# Unable to withdraw from Aave using contracts

Tags: solidity, polygon, defi, aave, usdc

I am using Polygon mainnet. Below are the steps I am trying to follow.

```
address private constant _lendingPoolAddressesProvider = 0xd05e3E715d945B59290df0ae8eF85c1BdB684744;
address private constant USDC_POLY_ADDRESS = 0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174;

ILendingPoolAddressesProvider addressesProvider = ILendingPoolAddressesProvider(_lendingPoolAddressesProvider);
ILendingPool lendingPool = ILendingPool(addressesProvider.getLendingPool());

ERC20 usdc = ERC20(USDC_POLY_ADDRESS);
uint16 referralCode = 0;

function deposit(uint256 amount, address to) external {
    require(amount > 0, "Amount needs to be greater than 0");

    // Transfer USDC to this contract
    usdc.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

    // Approve contract to deposit it into the lendingPool
    usdc.increaseAllowance(address(lendingPool), amount);

    // Actually deposit into the lendingPool on behalf of the to address
    lendingPool.deposit(address(usdc), amount, to, referralCode);
}

function withdraw(address to) external {
    lendingPool.withdraw(address(usdc), type(uint).max, to);
}
```

The deposit function is working fine but the withdraw function is failing.
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x9621fdfe18ed2c634a2ed4b5c2c9e139968519a5ca9036a3fa0e1e8d10d8c97b

Can someone please help decode this.

Thanks.

Comment: you have not deposited, while checking your contract the only two things you did were deploy and withdraw https://polygonscan.com/address/0x1233807b11fa01d16908743ea7fc55eaed5929b3

Comment: The `to` address I'm using in the withdraw has already used the deposit method and deposit some funds into aave in a separate transaction